# How to make one MySQL table related to any other table in a scalable way?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called "comments". I want the table to be able to relate to any other table in the database. For example, say I had the tables "users", "projects" and "tasks". I want to be able to relate a comment to any row in any of those tables.

My current solution is a single table called "comments_relations" which has 4 columns: "id", "comment_id", "foreign_table" and "foreign_table_id". This works well, but there is one crippling problem: The "comments" table isn't *actually* related to any other table, so I don't get any of the advantages of foreign keys. When a project is deleted, I want all related comments to be deleted as well, and the same goes for users and tasks, and any future table I add.

With the experience I have, I can only picture two real solutions (both bad, in my opinion):

1. Add a nullable column to the "comments" table for every related table, for instance "user_id", "project_id" and "task_id". I can define a foreign key on all those columns and get the behaviour I want. But what about the day when I have 10 tables that require comments? And then 20? I don't think this is a very scalable solution.
2. Add another table for every related table, for instance "users_comments", "projects_comments" etcetera that links each table to the comments table. This keeps the "comments" table clean, but again, this will nearly double the amount of tables in my database. And what if I add another table that should be relate-able to other tables? This doesn't scale.

An ideal solution would be the solution I'm currently using, but somehow supercharged to grant me the features of foreign keys.

### The summarized question:

What is the most scalable way of defining a table that can be related to *any amount* of other tables?

Comment: Are the comments specific to and and exclusive to one set of data, I'm assuming?

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking out loud and assuming you want to maintain 1 comments table, but what about assigning an ID to each table.  Something like this:

```
ID  |  table_name
-----------------
 1  |  users
 2  |  projects
 3  |  tasks
```

Then in your comments table you just have a column for the table ID and then the specific row ID for the user/projects/tasks data:

```
ID  |  table_id  |  data_id  |  comment
---------------------------------------------------
 1  |     1      |    468    |  yadda yadda yadda
 2  |     2      |    915    |  yadda yadda yadda
 3  |     1      |    195    |  yadda yadda yadda
 4  |     3      |    731    |  yadda yadda yadda
 5  |     1      |     5     |  yadda yadda yadda
```

There would be a bit of overhead to set up the initial association table, but I don't see that being terrible since the addition/deletion of tables doesn't tend to be dynamic.

Comment: Is this any different from what I'm doing now? I mean, is it possible to set up a foreign key system that will delete the comment if the record it's pointing to is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

normalise vs denormalise.

Normalise: basically you said everything.

- 1 comment table per table, using FK references
- pros: fast and clean
- cons: table maintenance maybe? Lots of tables. But with a good generator it should be ok. You decide.

Denormalise: (partially meta-modelising)

- 1 table `commentable_object`: `id`, `name` (task/project/user..expandable in 1 insert. This is the table where you define the types of object that accept comments. The volume is low, a few inserts only, because it consists in linearising your old DDL)
- 1 table `commentable_object_instance`: `id`, `object_name` (task/project/user), `otherpropsofyourchoice` - This is the table of your actual tasks, users etc.
- 1 table `comment`: `id`, `text`, #`id_commentable_object_instance` (fk to previous table)
- pros: one insert in the main `commentable_object` table and you're done with the model upgrade
- cons: performances lower than normalised model